# Failed to load template: uib/template/modal/window.html (HTTP status 404 Not Found)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've added ui-bootstrap to an angular 1.x project and getting this error when I want to open a modal form

> [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: uib/template/modal/window.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)

I've used ui-bootstrap before and always it worked well but in my new project I have problem with it.

the code is like :

```
$uibModal.open(
{ backdrop: 'static', templateUrl: 'DesktopModules/' + 
  window.GLOB.moduleFolderName + '/app/form/form.html',
  controller: 'requestCtrl',
  size: 'sm',
  scope: $scope 
 });
```

angular ver : v1.5.8

UIBS: v2.2.0

Bootstrap: v3.3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'ved solved the problem , 
we used 
    $templateCache.removeAll();
to always has a fresh version of files not cached ones and this functionality interferes with loading template files of ui bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the modal template `uib/template/modal/window.html`

Be sure you loaded  `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`

The `tpls` tag means that the file contains templates.

---

For reference:

#### ui-bootstrap-tpls.js

```
angular.module("ui.bootstrap"
 ["ui.bootstrap.tpls"
 "ui.bootstrap.transition"
"ui.bootstrap.collapse"
"ui.bootstrap.accordion"
"ui.bootstrap.alert"
"ui.bootstrap.bindHtml"
"ui.bootstrap.buttons"
"ui.bootstrap.carousel"
"ui.bootstrap.position"
"ui.bootstrap.datepicker"
"ui.bootstrap.dropdownToggle"
"ui.bootstrap.modal"
"ui.bootstrap.pagination"
"ui.bootstrap.tooltip"
"ui.bootstrap.popover"
"ui.bootstrap.progressbar"
"ui.bootstrap.rating"
"ui.bootstrap.tabs"
"ui.bootstrap.timepicker"
"ui.bootstrap.typeahead"]);

angular.module("ui.bootstrap.tpls"
 ["template/accordion/accordion-group.html"
"template/accordion/accordion.html"
"template/alert/alert.html"
"template/carousel/carousel.html"
"template/carousel/slide.html"
"template/datepicker/datepicker.html"
"template/datepicker/popup.html"
"template/modal/backdrop.html"
"template/modal/window.html"   //     < ---- Your case
"template/pagination/pager.html"
"template/pagination/pagination.html"
"template/tooltip/tooltip-html-unsafe-popup.html"
"template/tooltip/tooltip-popup.html"
"template/popover/popover.html"
"template/progressbar/bar.html"
"template/progressbar/progress.html"
"template/rating/rating.html"
"template/tabs/tab.html"
"template/tabs/tabset-titles.html"
"template/tabs/tabset.html"
"template/timepicker/timepicker.html"
"template/typeahead/typeahead-match.html"
"template/typeahead/typeahead-popup.html"]);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.transition'
 [])
```

Comment: I've added the mentioned file but the problem was something else.

Comment: @MahyarPasarzangene did you find the issue? how did you add the file?